# Why are repeated days incorrect with this RRULE?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

This should be a 2 hour 50 minute event starting at 5pm PST on a thursday evening repeating weekly. When imported into google calendar or Evolution, the first occurrence is correct, but subsequent weeks have the event on Wednesdays.

```
DTSTART:20170908T000000Z
DTEND:20170908T025000Z
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20171201T080000Z;BYDAY=TH
```

Other events that my application generate occur on multiple days i.e. `BYDAY=TH,TU` so simply removing the `BYDAY` is not a solution for my problem.

Comment: what is your expected outcome?

Comment: You might be having time zone issues. According to RFC-5545, `Z` indicates UTC time, but Google Calendar typically has a time zone associated with your individual calendar(s). What is your calendar's time zone? Settings (Gear icon) > Time zone.

Comment: @noogui the expected outcome would be the event repeating weekly on thursdays. (since its `BYDAY=TH`) Instead, the first event is at the correct time on thursday, and the subsequent repeated events are on wednesdays.
@rianjs The timezone in google calendar is set to -8. This issue also occurs in Evolution so I am assuming I have some misunderstanding of the spec rather than it being an issue with google calendar settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the timezone of the event and the display timezone. As far as recurrence calculation goes, the only thing that counts is the timezone that you declare in the VEVENT. Here you are using UTC. So:

The first instance is on the 20170908 which is a Friday. From there, you ask for a recurrence every thursday. The next thursday after 20170908 is 20170914, so the next instance starts on 20170914T000000Z.

When viewed with a display timezone of PST, this event has indeed its first instance on Thursday evening. But the second instance, as calculated above, is on a Thursday UTC time, so on a Wednesday PST time.

Besides this particular issue, you also need to worry about daylight saving changes. If your event is really taking place in PST timezone, the event, as expressed above will see its time change in November, after the DST transition takes place.

Hence it is almost never a good idea to express a recurring event by using UTC (Zulu) time.

You should have your event expressed in local time with timezone, i.e. use:

```
DTSTART;TZID="America/Los_Angeles":20170907T170000
```